How to load different JSON files with multiple objects inside and variable fields
I'm facing a situation where I need to load different JSON files with multiple objects inside each, and these files may have variable fields.
My goal is: I need to load two dataframes 1 with the source file (Which I have no issues loading it) and to compare with the result file which is the JSON at my question. I need to compare The column names and the values. I would like to load all the columns of the JSON file at my question in just 1 dataframe, but when I try to load it using only pd.read_json the format got completly messed up.
To add more context, I need to automate a test to compare the sources files (which are not a problem, because their format IS ok to work with) to the JSON files that I'm going to get from the API.
The problem is, this the current format of the JSON file, it has multiple objects in the same file, and the fields may vary:
      {
        "ingestionHeader": {
            "geo": "BR",
            "dataDomain": "BR_CNSMR_HDR",
            "dataSubDomain": "ADDRESS",
            "dataViewName": "NPUR_BR_CNSMR_HDR_ADDRESS_VIEW",
            "dataViewVersion": "1.0.0",
            "correlationId": "98ebe962-5766-49b1-8bb7-ac32f5fe3d75",
            "sourceId": "8c236374-a72f-4719-a801-3473333f259d",
            "regulatory": false,
            "sourceTimestamp": 1730276037830,
            "recordUUID": "dba020d9-7d7c-4a73-90e9-f4d23d040153",
            "sourceRecordUUID": "dba020d9-7d7c-4a73-90e9-f4d23d040153",
            "recordNumber": 1,
            "entityKey": "",
            "matchKey": "rDnzVxLfPq0Kahk9JSwLCFZGBm+gg1vwyM+7SlbyO/4RPvQzKi9tJzIBYv0C7qc9ueihBE64MC8zNdlcdtiyAA==",
            "previousMatchKey": null,
            "aggregatorId": null,
            "dfContributorName": "BVS",
            "dfContributionName": "",
            "dfCorrelationId": "5b78d691-cca0-44b3-8e85-6c52f77a76ca",
            "dfSourceId": "8c236374-a72f-4719-a801-3473333f259d",
            "dfSourceTimestamp": 1730275570449,
            "supplierId": "SUP111BVS",
            "dateReported": 1721411970000,
            "dateConversion": "SOURCE",
            "recordAction": null,
            "additionalInfo": {
                "supplierSourceRecordId": "",
                "dfSourceRecordUUID": "dba020d9-7d7c-4a73-90e9-f4d23d040153",
                "recordHash": "710d6b4adf04e95fa7e9cfbc681725936c5622180c3ca51b2f3e9348149a3645"
            },
            "dfContributionId": null,
            "contributionId": null,
            "memberId": "MEM111BVS",
            "journalingTimestamp": 1730276206258
        },
        "protectionInfo": {
            "unprotected": true,
            "protectionTime": 1730276037831,
            "keyGenTime": 1727369754998,
            "keyId": "691c2b9d-a611-4cb9-a42a-b4d4af9547d0",
            "keyBytes": null,
            "keystoreId": "479b6680-2784-435d-8638-db04a59849b0",
            "keyIndex": 10,
            "publicKeyType": null,
            "asymmetricKeyUrl": null,
            "asymmetricKeyVersion": null,
            "asymmetricMd5": null,
            "additionalInfo": null,
            "encryptionMeta": "bu0006u0010u0002u001Au00051.0.0"
        },
        "metadata": {
            "originCode": "45",
            "sourceCode": "155",
            "informantCode": "KND11867",
            "informantIdNumber": null,
            "updateUserId": null,
            "dataCondition": "Inibido",
            "originatingPurpose": "1",
            "internalBVSId": "1",
            "dateTimeInclusion": "2024-07-19T17:59:30+00:00",
            "dateTimeInclusionFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX",
            "_dateTimeInclusionEpoch": 1721411970000,
            "loadBatchId": "21905"
        },
        "consumerIdNumber": "",
        "_consumerIdNumberHashed": "",
        "dateTimeCapture": null,
        "dateTimeCaptureFormat": null,
        "address": {
            "propertyICMSRate": null,
            "installationCode": null,
            "typeAddress": null,
            "state": "PE",
            "dateBeginRelation": null,
            "dateBeginRelationFormat": null,
            "dateBeginResidence": null,
            "dateBeginResidenceFormat": null,
            "zipCode": null,
            "complementAddress": null,
            "iBGECodeCity": "",
            "streetName": null,
            "addressLatitude": null,
            "addressLongitude": null,
            "neighborhood": "GOIANA",
            "cityName": "74",
            "addressNumber": "",
            "typeStreet": null,
            "letterProtocolId": null,
            "typeZipCode": "0",
            "returnCodeAddress": "0",
            "returnCodeZipCode": null,
            "streetNameId": "",
            "addressNumberId": "b664f22125061b58605b0510a35443ab",
            "addressComplementId": "7",
            "metricAddress": ""
        }
    } 
    

I tried to use a simple command to load the file into a dataframe using pandas, but the result got completely confused.

I'm honestly unsure what your goal is and what your according question is. Can you clarify, perhaps with an example of appropriate (the above is way too much) size?

what are the distinct objects ? what do you want results to be (show actual expected results from actual inputs). Share the code you have written along with how it is invoked etc.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My goal is: I need to load two dataframes 1 with the source file (as I said before I have no issues loading it) and to compare with the result file which is the JSON at my question. I need to compare The column names and the values. I would like to load all the columns of the JSON file at my question in just 1 dataframe, but when I try to load it using only pd.read_json the format got completly messed up.

Why do you feel pandas should be part of the solution here?

you can flip the json objects to python dictionaries then test for equality dict=json.loads(object) .... , deepdiff module will show the differences ..., don't see any need for anything other (ie pandas .... ), but you may need to elaborate
